# Allow listing of subfolders on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having an issue with hosting a static website on Amazon S3. When forwarding to a folder containing a index.html file it always returns a AccessDenied response.

So accessing domain.com/en/index.html works but domain.com/en gives AccessDenied.

Anyone an idea?

My bucket policy is

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::domain.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How are you accessing the bucket? Are you using the Static Website Hosting URL? How is `domain.com` configured in Route 53 -- does it point to the bucket, or the static website hosting alias?

Answer (score 0):

Your bucket policy is correct. What is happening is that `domain.com/en` doesn't forward your request to `domain.com/en/index.html`, so Amazon S3 thinks that you're requesting the object `en` inside the bucket's root folder.

To forward your request to index.html put a slash after your initial path, like `domain.com/en/`.

Check this AWS documentation below to more information:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html

Comment: Even when trying to access domain.com/en/ it gives me an AccessDenied response. When I change the Public Access Control List to List Objects of Everyone to true it gives me InvalidKey response. The index file is set to index.html and there is an index.html file in the en/ folder.

Comment: Are you using CloudFront in front of S3?